# Count all possible triangles

Tags: python, big-o

I have 3 lists each containing some integers. 
Now I have to find out how many Triangles can I make such that each side of the triangle is from a different list.

```
A = [3,1,2]
B = [1,5] 
C = [2,4,1] 

Possible Triangles:
3,5,4
1,1,1
2,1,2
2,5,4
```

So answer should be 4.

I tried using three loops and using the triangle property where sum of any two sides is always greater than the third. But the time complexity for this O(n^3). I want something more faster.

```
count = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        for k in range(len(c)):
            if (a[i]+b[j] > c[k]) and (a[i]+c[k] > b[j]) and (c[k]+b[j] > a[i]):
                count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I tried using three loops and using the triangle property where sum of two sides is always greater than the third. But the time complexity for this O(n^3). I want something more faster.

Comment: You should share your current code, even if it is flawed, as a starting point.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I would appreciate if you share any useful information.

Comment: 1,1,1 isn’t a triangle.

Comment: @barny if these are the lengths, then it is a triangle

Comment: @barny Why can you please elaborate?

Comment: Where did the OP say these are lengths?

Comment: A "side of a triangle" as an integer sounds like its length to me. And the expected output is clear.

Comment: Ok, so why isn’t 3,1,2 in the “possible” answers? and 3,1,1 and 3,1,4

Comment: Because all those three are not triangles. You can't have a triangle with sides of 3, 1, 1.

Comment: @barny 3,1,2 isn't there because 1+2 = 3, please learn about triangles.

Comment: The code helps, a lot, especially once it’s explicit that the numbers are lengths.

Comment: @barny then please vote to reopen

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Please Vote so that we can have discussions on this, I have added all the details in the question as you suggested.

Comment: @barny Please Upvote and please don't put this question on hold. Suggest me what edits can I make in the question.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee I've wracked my brain all night, and I cannot come up with a way to get rid of the `log(n)` factor in my solution. Have you looked at my answer, and do you think it is correct, with its `O(n^2 log n)` running time?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee just edited my answer to add a variant with a best case `O(n^2)`, although it still has the same worst case. And I think I have an idea - not fully developed yet - for another algorithm that would have average case `O(n^2)` - see the part where I talk about sorting `B`. This question really is a lot of fun, thanks for asking it!

Comment: I came up with an `O(n^2)` algorithm today, do you still care for more answers? If so, I'll find time to write it up.

Comment: @joanis Ya Joa I care about your answers, its just that I am out of town so couldn't reply

Comment: OK, it's late here now, but I'll come back to it then.

Comment: @joanis Ya sure friend, I will be waiting for your solution. Anyways can I get your email or Facebook, so that we can connect there?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee there you go, the `O(n^2)` solution si now up. I'd be happy to connect, but I don't need how to send a private message on this platform, and I don't want to publish my fb or email. If you're willing to share yours here, though, I'll be happy to contact you then.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee So, how do you like the `O(n^2)` algorithm? It will take some careful programming work to actually implement, but should give a nice speed up if the lists are very long. I would guesstimate that the threshold is around `n` on the order of a thousand before it's faster than the simpler `O(n^2 log n)` algorithm, which can probably be done with existing binary search implementations is common libraries, unlike the merge, which will have to be custom-written.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee please consider upvoting if my answer is useful. I know it's not the Python code you hoped for, but I hope you will recognize I worked hard on your question and gave you good ideas on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

What's the `O` of this code?

```
import itertools as it
[sides for sides in it.product(A, B, C) if max(sides) < sum(sides) / 2.]
```

Comment: OK, your code does the same (only is much more written code and thus probably marginally slower than mine). You could optimize a little bit in pre-sorting the lists and choosing their right order, but going down to O(n^2 logn) isn't probably worth the code that would literally explode.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Jump to the bottom for an `O(n^2)` solution I found later, but which builds on the ideas in my previous solutions.

**Solution 1: use binary search to get `O(n^2 log(n))`**

Pseudo code:

```
C_s = sort C in ascending order
for a in A:
   for b in B:
      use binary search to find the highest index c_low in C_s s.t. C_s[c_low] <= |a-b|
      use binary search to find lowest index c_high in C_s s.t. C_s[c_high] >= a+b
      count += (c_high-c_low-1)
```

Explanation and demonstration of correctness:

- given the pair `(a,b)`:

  - values of `c` from `C_s[0]` to `C_s[c_low]` are too short to make a triangle
  - values of `c` from `C_s[c_high]` to `C_s[end]` are too large
  - there are `c_high-c_low-1` values of `c` between `c_high` and `c_low`, excluding the end points themselves, that will make a valid triangle with sides `(a,b,c)`
- I assume the standard binary search behaviour of returning an index just past either end if all values in `C_s` are either `> |a-b|` or `< a+b`, as if `C_s[-1] = -infinity` and `C_s[end+1] = +infinity`.

**Solution 2: cache values to get best case `O(n^2)` but worse case `O(n^2 log n)`**

The algorithm above can be improved with a cache for the results of the binary searches. If you cache them in an associative array with insert and lookup both `O(1)`, then this is faster in the best case, and probably also in the average case, depending on the distribution of inputs:

```
C_s = sort C in ascending order
low_cache = empty associative array
high_cache = empty associative array
for a in A:
   for b in B:
      if |a-b| in low_cache:
         c_low = low_cache{|a-b|}
      else:
         use binary search to find the highest index c_low in C_s s.t. C_s[c_low] <= |a-b|
         set low_cache{|a-b|} = c_low
      if a+b in high_cache:
         c_high = high_cache{a+b}
      else:
         use binary search to find lowest index c_high in C_s s.t. C_s[c_high] >= a+b
         set high_cache{a+b} = c_high
      count += (c_high-c_low-1)
```

- Best case analysis: if A and B are both `{1 .. n}`, i.e. the `n` numbers between 1 and `n`, then the binary search for `c_low` will be called `n` times, and the binary search for `c_high` will be called `2*n-1` times, and the rest of the time the results will be found in the cache.
  So the inner loop does `2*n^2` cache lookups with total time `O(2*n^2 * 1) = O(n^2)`, plus `3*n-1` binary searches with total time `O((3*n-1) log n) = O(n log n)`, with an overall best-case time of `O(n^2)`.
- Worst case analysis: the cache misses every time, we're back to the original algorithm with its `O(n^2 log n)`.
- Average case: this all depends on the distribution of inputs.

**More ideas I thought of**

- You might be able to make it faster by sorting A and B too. EDIT: see solution 3 below for how to get rid of the `log n` factor by sorting `B`. I haven't yet found a way to improve it further by sorting `A`, though.
- For Example, if you sort `B`, as you move to the next `b`, you can assume the next `c_low` is greater than the previous if `|a-b|` is greater, or vice versa. Similar logic applies to `c_high`. EDIT: the merge idea in solution 3 takes advantage of exactly this fact.
- An easy optimization if `A`, `B` and `C` are of different sizes: make C the largest one of the three lists.
- Another idea that doesn't actually help, but that I think is worth describing to guide further thought:

  - calculate all the values of `|a-b|` and `a+b` and store them in an array (time: `O(n^2)`)
  - sort that array (`O((n^2)log(n^2))=O(n^2 log n)`) -- this is the step that breaks the idea and brings us back to `O(n^2 log n)`,
  - use a merge algorithm between than sorted array and `C_sorted` (`O(n^2+n)=O(n^2)`) to extract the info from the results.

  That is very fuzzy pseudo code, I know, but if sorting the array of `n^2` elements could somehow be made faster, maybe by constructing that array in a more clever way by sorting `A` and `B` first, maybe the whole thing could come down to `O(n^2)`, at the cost of significantly increased complexity. However, thinking about this overnight, I don't see how to get rid of the `log n` factor here: you could make `O(n)` sorted lists of `O(n)` elements and merge them, but merging `O(n)` lists brings the `log n` factor right back in - it may be somewhat faster, but only by a constant, the complexity class stays the same.

**Solution 3: use merge to bring it down to `O(n^2)`**

Trying to figure out I could how to take advantage of sorting `B`, I finally realized the idea was simple: use the merging algorithm of merge sort, which can merge two sorted lists of `n` elements in `2*n - 1` comparisons, but modify it to calculate `c_low` and `c_high` (as defined in solution 1) for all elements of `B` in `O(n)` operations.

For `c_high`, this is simple, because `{a+b for b in B}` sorts in the same order as `B`, but for `c_low` it will take two merging passes, since `{|a-b| for b in B}` is descending as `b` increases up to `b<=a`, and ascending again for `b>=a`.

Pseudo code:

```
B_s = sort B in ascending order
C_s = sort C in ascending order
C_s_rev = reverse C_s

for a in A:
   use binary search to find the highest index mid where B_s[mid] <= a
   use an adapted merge over B_s[0..mid] and C_s_rev to calculate c_low_i for i in 0 .. mid
   use an adapted merge over B_s[mid+1..end_B] and C_s to calculate c_low_i for i in mid+1 .. end_B

   use an adapted merge over B_s and C_s to calculate c_high_i for i in range(len(B_s))

   for i in 0 .. end_B:
      count += c_high_i - c_low_i - 1
```

Big-Oh analysis: the body of the loop takes `O(log(n) + 2n + 2n + 2n + n) = O(n)` and runs `n` times (over the elements of `A`) yielding a total complexity class of `O(n^2)`.